# Send message to actor after restart from Supervisor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am using BackoffSupervisor strategy to create a child actor that has to process some message. I want to implement a very simple restart strategy, in which in case of exception:

1. Child propagates failing message to supervisor
2. Supervisor restarts child and sends the failing message again.
3. Supervisor gives up after 3 retries
4. Akka persistence is **not** an option

So far what I have is this:

Supervisor definition:

```
val childProps = Props(new SenderActor())
val supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onFailure(
    childProps,
    childName = cmd.hashCode.toString,
    minBackoff = 1.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 2.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2 
  )
    .withSupervisorStrategy(
      OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 3, loggingEnabled = true) {
        case msg: MessageException => {
          println("caught specific message!")
          SupervisorStrategy.Restart
        }
        case _: Exception => SupervisorStrategy.Restart
        case _              ⇒ SupervisorStrategy.Escalate
      })
)

val sup = context.actorOf(supervisor)


sup ! cmd
```

Child actor that is supposed to send the e-mail, but fails (throws some Exception) and propagates Exception back to supervisor:

```
class SenderActor() extends Actor {

  def fakeSendMail():Unit =  {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    throw new Exception("surprising exception")
  } 

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case cmd: NewMail =>

      println("new mail received routee")
      try {
        fakeSendMail()
      } catch {
        case t => throw MessageException(cmd, t)
      }

  }
}
```

In the above code I wrap any exception into custom class MessageException that gets propagated to SupervisorStrategy, but how to propagate it further to the new child to force reprocessing? Is this the right approach?

Edit. I attempted to resent the message to the Actor on `preRestart` hook, but somehow the hook is not being triggered:

```
class SenderActor() extends Actor {

  def fakeSendMail():Unit =  {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    //    println("mail sent!")
    throw new Exception("surprising exception")
  }

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    println("child starting")
  }


  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
    reason match {
      case m: MessageException => {
        println("aaaaa")
        message.foreach(self ! _)
      }
      case _ => println("bbbb")
    }
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    println("child stopping")
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case cmd: NewMail =>

      println("new mail received routee")
      try {
        fakeSendMail()
      } catch {
        case t => throw MessageException(cmd, t)
      }

  }
}
```

This gives me something similar to following output:

```
new mail received routee
caught specific message!
child stopping
[ERROR] [01/26/2018 10:15:35.690]
[example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]
[akka://example/user/persistentActor-4-scala/$a/1962829645] Could not
process message sample.persistence.MessageException:
Could not process message <stacktrace>
child starting
```

But no logs from `preRestart` hook

Comment: With `Backoff.onFailure`, when the child of the `BackoffSupervisor` restarts, the child's `preRestart` method is not called, because the [underlying supervisor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.9/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/BackoffOnRestartSupervisor.scala) actually stops the child, then starts it again later.

Comment: Exactly the issue. Is there any way around this and still be able to reuse backoff supervisor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that the child's `preRestart` hook is not invoked is because `Backoff.onFailure` uses [`BackoffOnRestartSupervisor`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.9/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/BackoffOnRestartSupervisor.scala) underneath the covers, which replaces the default restart behavior with a stop-and-delayed-start behavior that is consistent with the backoff policy. In other words, when using `Backoff.onFailure`, when a child is restarted, the child's `preRestart` method is not called because the underlying supervisor actually stops the child, then starts it again later. (Using [`Backoff.onStop`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/pattern/Backoff$.html#onStop(childProps:akka.actor.Props,childName:String,minBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maxBackoff:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,randomFactor:Double):akka.pattern.BackoffOptions) can trigger the child's `preRestart` hook, but that's tangential to the present discussion.)

The `BackoffSupervisor` API doesn't support the automatic resending of a message when the supervisor's child restarts: you have to implement this behavior yourself. An idea for retrying messages is to let the `BackoffSupervisor`'s supervisor handle it. For example:

```
val supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onFailure(
    ...
  ).withReplyWhileStopped(ChildIsStopped)
  ).withSupervisorStrategy(
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 3, loggingEnabled = true) {
      case msg: MessageException =>
        println("caught specific message!")
        self ! Error(msg.cmd) // replace cmd with whatever the property name is
        SupervisorStrategy.Restart
      case ...
    })
)

val sup = context.actorOf(supervisor)

def receive = {
  case cmd: NewMail =>
    sup ! cmd
  case Error(cmd) =>
    timers.startSingleTimer(cmd.id, Replay(cmd), 10.seconds)
    // We assume that NewMail has an id field. Also, adjust the time as needed.
  case Replay(cmd) =>
    sup ! cmd
  case ChildIsStopped =>
    println("child is stopped")
}
```

In the above code, the `NewMail` message embedded in the `MessageException` is wrapped in a custom case class (in order to easily distinguish it from a "normal"/new `NewMail` message) and sent to `self`. In this context, `self` is the actor that created the `BackoffSupervisor`. This enclosing actor then uses a [single timer](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actors-timers) to replay the original message at some point. This point in time should be far enough in the future such that the `BackoffSupervisor` can potentially exhaust `SenderActor`'s restart attempts, so that the child can have ample opportunity to get in a "good" state before it receives the resent message. Obviously this example involves only one message resend regardless of the number of child restarts.

---

Another idea is to create a `BackoffSupervisor`-`SenderActor` pair for every `NewMail` message, and have the `SenderActor` send the `NewMail` message to itself in the `preStart` hook. One concern with this approach is the cleaning up of resources; i.e., shutting down the `BackoffSupervisors` (which will, in turn, shut down their respective `SenderActor` children) when the processing is successful or when the child restarts are exhausted. A map of `NewMail` ids to `(ActorRef, Int)` tuples (in which the `ActorRef` is a reference to a `BackoffSupervisor` actor, and the `Int` is the number of restart attempts) would be helpful in this case:

```
class Overlord extends Actor {

  var state = Map[Long, (ActorRef, Int)]() // assuming the mail id is a Long

  def receive = {
    case cmd: NewMail =>
      val childProps = Props(new SenderActor(cmd, self))
      val supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.props(
        Backoff.onFailure(
          ...
        ).withSupervisorStrategy(
          OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 3, loggingEnabled = true) {
            case msg: MessageException =>
              println("caught specific message!")
              self ! Error(msg.cmd)
              SupervisorStrategy.Restart
            case ...
          })
      )
      val sup = context.actorOf(supervisor)
      state += (cmd.id -> (sup, 0))

    case ProcessingDone(cmdId) =>
      state.get(cmdId) match {
        case Some((backoffSup, _)) =>
          context.stop(backoffSup)
          state -= cmdId
        case None =>
          println(s"${cmdId} not found")
      }

    case Error(cmd) =>
       val cmdId = cmd.id
       state.get(cmdId) match {
         case Some((backoffSup, numRetries)) =>
           if (numRetries == 3) {
             println(s"${cmdId} has already been retried 3 times. Giving up.")
             context.stop(backoffSup)
             state -= cmdId
           } else
             state += (cmdId -> (backoffSup, numRetries + 1))
         case None =>
           println(s"${cmdId} not found")
       }

    case ...
  }
}
```

Note that `SenderActor` in the above example takes a `NewMail` and an `ActorRef` as constructor arguments. The latter argument allows the `SenderActor` to send a custom `ProcessingDone` message to the enclosing actor:

```
class SenderActor(cmd: NewMail, target: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    println(s"child starting, sending ${cmd} to self")
    self ! cmd
  }

  def fakeSendMail(): Unit = ...

  def receive = {
    case cmd: NewMail => ...
  }
}
```

Obviously the `SenderActor` is set up to fail every time with the current implementation of `fakeSendMail`. I'll leave the additional changes needed in `SenderActor` to implement the happy path, in which `SenderActor` sends a `ProcessingDone` message to `target`, to you.

Answer (score 1):

In the good solution that @chunjef provides, he alert about the risk of schedule a job resend before the backoff supervisor has started the worker

> This enclosing actor then uses a single timer to replay the original message at some point. This point in time should be far enough in the future such that the BackoffSupervisor can potentially exhaust SenderActor's restart attempts, so that the child can have ample opportunity to get in a "good" state before it receives the resent message.

If this happens, the scenario will be jobs going to dead letters and no further progress will be done.
I've made a simplified fiddle with [this scenario](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/FhlnZCh/5).

So, the schedule delay should be larger than the maxBackoff, and this could represent an impact in job completion time.
A possible solution to avoid this scenario is making the worker actor to send a message to his father when is ready to work, like [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/QITPfLv/2).

Answer (score 0):

The failed child actor is available as the sender in your supervisor strategy. Quoting https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html#creating-a-supervisor-strategy:

> If the strategy is declared inside the supervising actor (as opposed
>   to within a companion object) its decider has access to all internal
>   state of the actor in a thread-safe fashion, including obtaining a
>   reference to the currently failed child (available as the sender of
>   the failure message).

Comment: *"If the strategy is declared inside the supervising actor (as opposed to within a companion object)...."* The strategy in this case is not declared inside the supervising actor but in the `BackoffOptions#withSupervisorStrategy` method.

Answer (score -1):

Sending emails is a dangerous operation with some third party software in your case. Why not to apply [Circuit Breaker](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/circuitbreaker.html) pattern and skip the sender actor entirely? Also, you can still have an actor (with some Backoff Supervisor) and Circuit Breaker inside it (if that makes sense for you).